# Question regarding 7402 IC

Tags: open-collector

I want to create a SR latch using [7402](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7402.pdf) IC. I would like to read the output (i.e. Q value) from the IC using an ADAM-6066 which has the following specs for digital input:

Wet contacts: Logic level 0: 0~3 VDC Logic level 1: 10~30 VDC

My question is:

1. Does the 7402 IC have open-collector output? The datasheet says nothing.
2. If the 7402 IC does not have a open-collector output then can I connect A [SN7407N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5417.pdf) IC to the output of 7402 IC and pull up the voltage from the output of SN7407N IC to 10-30VDC?

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: 30V(DC) is the absolute maximum rating of the SN7407, it isn't good practice to stress it near its limits. Keep a couple volts head room and the device's life span will be much better.

Comment: Read the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the datasheets for [7402](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7402.pdf) and [SN7407N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5417.pdf). @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is right. If the datasheet doesn't explicitly mention it, it is a push-pull output driver. The exact implementation varies with logic family (74xx, 74HCxx, 74LSxx, ...), but the concept remains the same: either push-pull or open collector (open drain).

Both datasheets have a schematic diagram of the circuit that is implemented in the IC. The circuit will in reality be a bit more complex, but it suffices for understanding what is going on in the chip.

Look at the output stage for **7402**:

[image]

and **7407**:

[image]

Clearly the 7402, in the top image, has a push-pull output stage with the two transistors, one attached to each power rail; and the 7407 has only a single transistor of which the collector is unconnected (open).

Answer (score 3):

The 7402 uses a push-pull output driver, which is the default if the datasheet doesn't mention open-collector or three-state outputs. But you don't want a OC output on them regardless, since they have to feed back into the other gate. You can put a 7407 after them to provide a OC output to the next stage.